# Is there possibility to federate SAML2 (or SAML1) IdP with ID-FF SP using openSSO (openAM)

Tags: saml, opensso

Is there possibility to federate SAML2 (or SAML1) IdP with ID-FF SP using openSSO (openAM)?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

This is document thats describes similar scenarios. It will apply to openam too.

[ID-FF Federation Operations in opensso.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19575-01/820-3885/ghmum/index.html)
See section: Configuring ID-FF Single Sign-on

Comment: I've seen it already. I wonder if there is possibility to attach remote idp (idff) + remote sp (idff or saml2).